# Why is date.day an attribute but not a method like date.today()?

Tags: python, datetime, methods, attributes

Why the use of an attribute for [0]date.day instead of a method like [1]date.today()

[0] https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.day

[1] https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.today

Answer (score 2):

day is a property of an date **object** (an instance of the class = any specific date), which does not change until the object changes.

today is a **class method**. It needs to be called to check the current date. It returns different results on different days. There is no object required to call this method.

To give an example:

```py
import datetime as dt

today = dt.date.today()  # returns value when code is executed
print(today)  # 2020-07-19 (or what ever day it is)

anotherday = dt.date(2001,01,01)  # defines a date object
day = anotherday.day
print(day)  # gives always 01
```